# Saving the video when app is interrupted by call

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

I setup and use AVAssetWriterInput --- AVAssetWriter chain to record a video. This works fine.
When the video recording is stopped, AVAssetWriter's finishWriting returns a status saying it is Completed.
However, if the recording is interrupted by a call then the finishWriting status says it is Failed and the video is not saved.

To fix this issue, following line of code is used.

self.assetWriter.movieFragmentInterval = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, 1000000000);

Here, even if the status says Failed, the video is saved.

Will this affect the performance, as the header is now added at regular intervals to the recording video?
Also, is it right to hard code the values say, 1000000000?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: You should be fine with this code. The only difference now is the quicktime container is a 'streaming' quicktime file. Performance should not be an issue at all.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your reply. I however faced few problems. It might be because of using movieFragmentInterval. A long recorded video(can be 5 - 10 mins)takes time to prepare and play using AVPlayer. YouTube will upload only 1 second of video. And sometimes, 40 - 50 mins video does not get saved at all.

Comment: It is possible youtube does not support the file type. It sounds like it stops after parseing the first atom tree in the file. In your case that will contain 1 second of AV data. AVPlayer may be buffering more data. I am not sure about this. I am also not sure why 40 - 50 min of video is not saved. Do you have enough space? The other option you could try is finish the recording if the app is interrupted. When it comes back auto start a new recording. After the user stops recording combine the videos with the editing classes in AVFoundation.